# Lodash.get и Typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash

В проекте используется редукс. Дефолтный стейт задан так:

```
const initialState: SubmissionsState = {
  submissions: {}
};
```

Указанный `SubmissionsState` выглядит так:

```
interface SubmissionsState {
  submissions: Submission | SubmissionEmpty;
}
```

где:

```
type ContestChallengePractice = {
  graded_score: number;
  total_score: number;
  delta_score_percent: number;
};

type Submission = {
  module: Modules;
  final_challenge: ContestChallengePractice;
  contest: ContestChallengePractice;
  practice: ContestChallengePractice;
};
```

Иными словами, мой дефолтный стейт это пустой объект `submissions: {}`, но, если приходят данные, то он превращается в:

```
submissions: {
  practice: {
    graded_score: 1,
    total_score: 1,
    delta_score_percent: 1
  }
...
}
```

А значит practice и вложенные в него свойства могут быть any.

Теперь, во вьюхе я хочу это рендерить. Пробовал так через Optional chaining:

```
data.submissions?.practice?.delta_score_percent
```

Ругается:

```
Property 'practice' does not exist on type 'Submission | {}'.
  Property 'practice' does not exist on type '{}'
```

Тогда я решил, что воспользуюсь lodash.get. Пробовал различные вариации lodash.get, но все они так или иначе возвращают ошибки

`get(data, 'submissions.practice.delta_score_percent', PLACEHOLDERS.NO_DATA);` -> `Unsafe assignment of an 'any' value.`

`get<SubmissionsState, string, string>(data, 'submissions.practice.total_score', PLACEHOLDERS.NO_DATA)` -> `Argument of type '"submissions.practice.delta_score_percent"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof SubmissionsState | [keyof SubmissionsState]'`

И др.

Попробовал воспроизвести проблему в codesandbox, но там get с тайпскриптом подружились. У себя в проекте @types/lodash установлены. Пробовал устанавливать и @types/lodash.get, не помогло.

Подскажите, пожалуйста =)

Comment: Ну ёлки, нельзя было в песочнице весь код собрать? Я вроде бы знаю, что поправить, но надо проверять.

Comment: @Qwertiy я честно пытался, но почему то get лодашовский там не давал ошибок! [Вот](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-leaf-1cxy9?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение:

```
type SubmissionEmpty = { [key in keyof Submission]?: undefined }
```

```
const x = data.submissions.practice?.delta_score_percent
```

А вот код полностью: [песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcBGBbYBnPYAexD1TDkmQG8BYAKGWTy1wONIC41X9CTkAHx44+HAKLYADmACeAbgYBfBgzlSUAYRKQ8YTQAs4AG2MQQAcwgAFKIjDAkyALw0GTC3YAmELwH08BCIoCG4QdGxMaEVGZDAiCmMAoJCwiKioGKYfYwpk4Ig-DSgkcDTI6OUYtVkNETZ+EBc3WIB6VuRsIi90M24AWW7eiDws5BhQEz8EI1NzK25tcBH9WbNLGzsEByQxoOW9RZ0VwxN1q1t7RwgxqS2d0OQl3VWz+c2r3arVenUUDFE7BIkhksma1GQAG0ANYQMGgZCw2REGD1MQkAC6AH5uOgQD4JiBfMgVPQGAA3OBQZBeShwbgAhocMgUKiuOixFiAxp4bjUJQAGmUP1pFHB7mYvCBXBaTCYd0+jw5crlnjgPn8gQK3AAjELYir4ol8qlkHqJSqcnktSEitBSmBdRaSfqVYSpjM3hs0qYAISuuX7F4+4z+iWC4Vk+j7PTIAAezVFcAAdFymSQ8MmFdtrljk1a4CbCsUHUA)

```
interface SubmissionsState {
  submissions: Submission | SubmissionEmpty;
}

type ContestChallengePractice = {
  graded_score: number;
  total_score: number;
  delta_score_percent: number;
};

type Submission = {
  // module: Modules;
  final_challenge: ContestChallengePractice;
  contest: ContestChallengePractice;
  practice: ContestChallengePractice;
};

type SubmissionEmpty = { [key in keyof Submission]?: undefined }

var data: SubmissionsState = {
  submissions: {},
}

data = {
  submissions: {
    practice: {
      graded_score: 1,
      total_score: 1,
      delta_score_percent: 1
    },
    final_challenge: null!,
    contest: null!,
  },
}

const x = data.submissions.practice?.delta_score_percent
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Ради спортивного интереса, какие параметры <> нужно было бы передать get, чтобы и get заработал?

Comment: @Mr.Brightside, подозреваю, что при этих тайпингах он и так заработает?